# Using .css.scss variables in jQuery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, sass

I am working on a Rails 3.1 app and am happily using SASS and CoffeeScript.  I particularly like the SASS extensions of variables and imports.  I have constructed a single _global-settings.css.scss file which contains ALL of the hex constant values I use throughout all of my stylesheets.  This gives me a single place to manage colors, fonts and layout dimensions.  Very DRY.

But, if I wish to use JQuery to tweak my css dynamically, I no longer have access to my css compile-time variables, and must reproduce the same data as a JSON hash in a .js.coffee file.  Not DRY at all.

Here is my question:  Before I go off and build a rake task to munge my css settings file into an equivalent CoffeeScript hash, does anyone have a more clever idea?  Like hiding all the values in a hidden div in an html file?

Comment: Not sure of this, I believe you can have a `constants.yml` file where you list your global values. Those can then be inserted into asset files via ERB, I believe. But I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @Flambino: That's the right idea: put the constants in Ruby-land and use ERB to get them into SASS and CoffeeScript. I don't know about `constants.yml` though, adding a `YAML.load_file` call during application initialization would be easy enough if it wasn't automatic.

Comment: @muistooshort The contants-file I remembered from when [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) was first introduced; before it became integrated into Rails. But that was quite some time ago, hence the "not sure" in my comment :)

Comment: @Flambino: And hence my "don't know ... but" :) I just generated a new 3.1 app and I don't see `constants.yml` anywhere so that's probably something that got dropped.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, it seems it's been removed. I also just played around in a 3.1 app, but didn't find anything either. Nice answer, by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have an easier time moving your CSS configuration into Ruby and then sending your `_global-settings.css.scss` and a small piece of CoffeeScript through ERB. Then you have your settings in place and you can access them everywhere.

Somewhere in Ruby you'd have this:

```
CSS_SETTINGS = {
    :text_color        => '#333',
    :text_color_hilite => '#f33',
    :font_size         => '14px',
    #...
}
```

Then rename your `_global-settings.css.scss` to `_global-settings.css.scss.erb` and use things like this inside it:

```
$text-color: '<%= CSS_SETTINGS[:text_color] %>';
// ...
```

And inside a `global_settings.js.coffee.erb` you could have this:

```
window.app.global_settings = <%= CSS_SETTINGS.to_json.html_safe %>
```

You could even write a simple view helper that would SASSify a Hash:

```
def sassify(h)
    h.map do |k, v|
        # You might want more escaping for k and v in here, this is just
        # a simple proof of concept demo.
        [ '$', k.to_s.gsub('_', '-'), ': ', "'#{v}'", ';' ].join
    end.join("\n")
end
```

and then you could say this in your `_global-settings.css.scss.erb`:

```
// Import global CSS settings.
<%= sassify(CSS_SETTINGS).html_safe %>
```

You could also monkey patch a `to_sass` into Hash and use `CSS_SETTINGS.to_sass` but that's probably taking things one step too far.

Comment: Thanks for the good ideas.  I will study them and make something work.